# "When I've pulled up your hat I've seen your braids" or should I use the past simple?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-present-perfect

Let's say I have just seen my daughter's braids under her hat. Should I say to her:

> Baby when I've pulled up your hat I've seen your braids

or

> Baby when I pulled up your hat I saw your braids

The 2nd one sounds the correct one to me because the "when" triggers the "past simple" in my head, but I'm not sure because the tense is still "now" (it just happened).

Comment: This one is related to my question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/163190/present-perfect-when-past-simple-present-perfect but I'm still clueless.

Comment: You are right that the second version is the correct one. It's true that we use the perfect tense when the action was recent enough to affect the present moment, but this doesn't apply to a 'when' clause.  "When I have pulled up your hat..." suggests "on [several] previous occasions".